# Chrome content.min.js error: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Google chrome and suddenly I started getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://nknfhhmhoflkcijaodalbncnmidocced/content.min.js:8
    at chrome-extension://nknfhhmhoflkcijaodalbncnmidocced/content.min.js:8
```

If I remove all my JS I still get this error...

What is going on there? And how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is coming from an extensions's content script that you've installed.  Go to Menu -> More tools -> Extensions and look for the one with ID `nknfhhmhoflkcijaodalbncnmidocced`.

Try to disable it for a while and see if the error comes up again.  If yes, either ignore it or remove the extension :)

That's the one - [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nknfhhmhoflkcijaodalbncnmidocced).

Comment: Genius that' s the one. Thanks! Is it a problem for my project?

Comment: Absolutely no problem, as content scripts run in a special sandboxed environment within the browser and there is no interference with your page code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem with the "MultiLogin" extension that you have.

Try disabling it.